# How do you access .NET Framework default SMTP service in Azure Functions? Using Postal in Azure Function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, postal

We are moving certain background methods that send emails to Azure functions. Our emails are currently built and sent using [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/)

Postal [uses .NET Framework’s built-in SmtpClient](http://aboutcode.net/postal/smtp-config.html), which has connection details defined in a web.config file for our MVC web app, which doesn't exist in an Azure Function.

Is there a way to use Postal in an Azure Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [look at the source code of the project on GitHub](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/blob/9b0e426aa79af93ce67b8b1a6f08d561f0f07248/src/Postal/EmailService.cs#L23), you'll see that Postal's EmailServer takes in a Func. If you don't provide it, it creates an SmtpClient by executing the `new SmtpClient()` constructor, which pulls configuration in from the .config file. So if you want avoid using a .config file to get the settings, pass in a Func.

```
public SmtpClient CreateMySmtpClient()
{
    var client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpserver.com");
    // set credentials, timeouts etc
    return client;
}

public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    var emailService = new EmailService(ViewEngines.Engines, CreateMySmtpClient);
    dynamic email = new Email("Test");
    email.Message = "Hello,  world!";
    emailService.Send(email);
}
```